# Parsing XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I can not figure out how to parse the "author" and "fact" tags out of the following XML.  If the formatting looks strange [here is a link](http://www.librarything.com/services/rest/1.1/?method=librarything.ck.getwork&isbn=0590353403&apikey=d231aa37c9b4f5d304a60a3d0ad1dad4) to the XML doc.

```
<response stat="ok">
−<ltml version="1.1">
   −<item id="5403381" type="work">
      <author id="21" authorcode="rowlingjk">J. K. Rowling</author>
      <url>http://www.librarything.com/work/5403381</url>
     −<commonknowledge>
     −<fieldList>
     −<field type="42" name="alternativetitles" displayName="Alternate titles">
     −<versionList>
     −<version id="3413291" archived="0" lang="eng">
         <date timestamp="1298398701">Tue, 22 Feb 2011 13:18:21 -0500</date>
         −<person id="18138">
             <name>ablachly</name>
             <url>http://www.librarything.com/profile/ablachly</url>
          </person>
         −<factList>
              <fact>Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone </fact>
           </factList>
              </version>
       </versionList>
      </field>
```

So far I have tried this code to get the author but it does not work:

```
@xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.librarything.com/services/rest/1.1/?method=librarything.ck.getwork&isbn=0590353403&apikey=d231aa37c9b4f5d304a60a3d0ad1dad4"))

@xml_doc.xpath('//response').each do |n|
    @author = n      
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get at any nodes deeper than `//response` using the link you provided. I ended up using `Nokogiri::XML::Reader` and pushing elements into a hash, since there may be multiple authors, and there are definitely multiple facts. You can use whatever data structure you like, but this gets the content of the `fact` and `author` tags:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.librarything.com/services/rest/1.1/?method=librarything.ck.getwork&isbn=0590353403&apikey=d231aa37c9b4f5d304a60a3d0ad1dad4"
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(url))

book = {
  author: []
  fact: []
}

reader.each do |node|
  book.each do |k,v|
    if node.name == k.to_s && !node.inner_xml.empty?
      book[k] << node.inner_xml
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
nodes = @xml_doc.xpath("//xmlns:author", "xmlns" => "http://www.librarything.com/")
puts nodes[0].inner_text

nodes = @xml_doc.xpath("//xmlns:fact", "xmlns" => "http://www.librarything.com/")
nodes.each do |n|
   puts n.inner_text
end
```

The trick is in the namespace.

Comment: The namespace is not shown in the xml fragment above but it appears if you watch the source code of your linked document

Comment: Because there is only one `author` tag it is simpler to use `@xml_doc.at` and `nodes.inner_text` or just `nodes.text`.